# Ordered colored plot after clustering using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, data-mining

I have a 1D array called data=[5 1 100 102 3 4 999 1001 5 1 2 150 180 175 898 1012]. I am using python scipy.cluster.vq to find clusters within it. There are 3 clusters in the data. After clustering when I'm trying to plot the data, there is no order in it.

It would be great if it's possible to plot the data in the same order as it is given and color different sections belong to different groups or clusters.

### Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, vq


data = np.loadtxt('rawdata.csv', delimiter=' ')
#----------------------kmeans------------------
centroid,_ = kmeans(data, 3) 
idx,_ = vq(data, centroid)
x=np.linspace(0,(len(data)-1),len(data))

fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,data)
plot1=plt.plot(data[idx==0],'ob')
plot2=plt.plot(data[idx==1],'or')
plot3=plt.plot(data[idx==2],'og')
plt.show()
```

---

Here is my plot 
http://s29.postimg.org/9gf7noe93/figure_1.png
(The blue graph in the background is in-order, after clustering,it messed up)

Thanks!

**Update :**

I wrote the following code to implement in-order colored plot after clustering,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, vq

data = np.loadtxt('rawdata.csv', delimiter=' ')
#----------------------kmeans-----------------------------
centroid,_ = kmeans(data, 3)  # three clusters
idx,_ = vq(data, centroid)
x=np.linspace(0,(len(data)-1),len(data))
fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,data)

for i in range(0,(len(data)-1)):
    if data[i] in data[idx==0]:
       plt.plot(x[i],(data[i]),'ob' )
    if data[i] in data[idx==1]:
       plt.plot(x[i],(data[i]),'or' )
    if data[i] in data[idx==2]:
       plt.plot(x[i],(data[i]),'og' )
 plt.show()
```

The problem with the above code is it's too slow. And my array size is over 3million. So this code will take forever to finish it's job for me. 
I really appreciate if someone can provide **vectorized version** of the above mentioned code.
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you plot x versus data? It plots data points based on their indices, do you need this plot?

Comment: @Dalek, I plotted x vs data to show the given order of the data. I really don't need x vs data plot if plot1, plot2, and plot3 are in the same order like x vs data plot. But it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot the clustered data points based on their distances from the cluster center and then write the index of each data point close to that in order to see how they scattered based on their clustering properties:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, vq
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
data=np.array([   5,    1,  100,  102,    3,    4,  999, 1001,    5,    1,    2,    150,  180,  175,  898, 1012])
centroid,_ = kmeans(data, 3) 
idx,_ = vq(data, centroid)
X=data.reshape(len(data),1)
Y=centroid.reshape(len(centroid),1)
D_k = cdist( X, Y, metric='euclidean' )
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
pId=range(0,(len(data)-1))
cIdx = [np.argmin(D) for D in D_k]
dist = [np.min(D) for D in D_k]
r=np.vstack((data,dist)).T
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
mark=['^','o','>']
for i, ((x,y), kls) in enumerate(zip(r, cIdx)):
    ax.plot(r[i,0],r[i,1],color=colors[kls],marker=mark[kls])
    ax.annotate(str(i), xy=(x,y), xytext=(0.5,0.5), textcoords='offset points',
                 size=8,color=colors[kls])


ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('Data')
ax.set_ylabel('Distance')
plt.show()
```

**Update**:

if you are very keen of using vectorize procedure you can do it as following for a randomly generated data:

```
data=np.random.uniform(1,1000,3000)
@np.vectorize
def plotting(i):
    ax.plot(i,data[i],color=colors[cIdx[i]],marker=mark[cIdx[i]])


mark=['>','o','^']
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plotting(range(len(data)))
ax.set_xlabel('index')
ax.set_ylabel('Data')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code. Is it possible to plot the data according to the given order based on their index (i.e 1st point 5(red),2nd point 1(red),3rd point 100(blue) and so on.I mean x-axis index, y-axis data points).but with different colors. The other problem is my file is too large(3million) so the for loop makes it very slow. Vectorization is essential to handle this kind of large data set.

Comment: @precision I updated the part that you might be interested more. I hope it is the answer you are looking for.